# Jasper Report: appear extra empty column in the end of table column

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jaspersoft studio 5.6.0. I created a table in summary band to display data from database. it generate extra empty column in the end of table. can anybody help me on this problem?

result in word:

[image]

[jrxml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwl5po5Q-3BvZmhWaFI4akY5OVE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you past the relevant jrxml in the question (edit question).... this is the only way we can help you...

Comment: just check that your last column on the right ends exactly on the edge of your band (even if it seems so in your second image)... when rendered in doc, xls, a jrxml has this strange behaviour

Comment: You should try to past as text the jrxml related to your table (in attached jrxml there are several tables), edit question. If so @Cameron can be more specific in his answer (he know what table you are having trouble with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Fabio Fantoni said in the comments, you need to make sure that your table width and column width match up.

Your **tables widths do not match up with the width of the columns** inside them (some by just a single pixel), this is probably causing the issue.

Here are the correct widths, but you should check them and adjust if needed:

> **First Table:** width = 428 px
>
> **Second Table:** width = 475 px
>
> **Third Table:** width = 474 px

These changes can be made in JasperSoft Studio without the need of direct editing of the source.

**Example**

The following is the `jrxml` for your `summary` band with the adjusted table widths to match the width of the columns inside the table. Any adjustment to the column sizes will required you to change the widths of the tables.

```
<summary>
    <band height="343">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="39" y="1" width="241" height="20" uuid="7ba83b4b-6038-4657-ae77-a50396d66cea"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[A.    Posisi TKA Baru yang disetujui :]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="39" y="83" width="58" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="e6d5218f-5d8d-4521-bad1-0697e09cfa3d"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[B.    Daftar ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="39" y="160" width="58" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="f797ef70-f498-40e0-9f35-181c0bf16933"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[C.    Daftar]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table 17" style="table 17" positionType="Float" x="39" y="21" width="428" height="57" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6fb859a1-5044-47bd-9249-63fa455470aa">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 1" uuid="84090836-d798-43a0-93bc-3cde0db803f2">
                    <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS1}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="28" uuid="3363640b-30fb-4c36-b1f6-bc0a53cda03d">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="28" height="30" uuid="bd296baa-e9fe-43de-900e-7c71cd341787"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[No.]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="28" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="128b482b-45e2-4f5c-aeaf-87807921e469"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="136" uuid="20b03b70-6219-4d3b-8261-90b28ca98420">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="136" height="30" uuid="4981f674-08fc-473e-8c5b-fef5b708f14d"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Posisi TKA]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="136" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="7e868880-19a9-4d1d-be80-b75f7b508427"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{posisiTka}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="67" uuid="0bd520ee-899a-4a09-a728-40b7e0ded152">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="67" height="30" uuid="5db7fe89-668a-47f1-a74d-89845dc000c9"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Dept.]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="67" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="44c8d21d-f8d0-4728-8270-0655cf9c02bf"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{departemen}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="88" uuid="41258d68-dd01-4e48-b59e-cdf94f31bd4a">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="88" height="30" uuid="b5d619ef-d7df-4ce1-9684-ac667f2123e7"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Periode Penggunaan]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="88" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6ace5c77-cebd-480c-994d-31c593dfe1c9"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{periode}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="109" uuid="0923900a-06e1-46b5-9b06-d7cbd97cea32">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="109" height="30" uuid="7dda780f-29a0-44be-a5bf-de7c059c8b1e"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Keterangan]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="109" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="683f9507-e3dd-4afe-88bf-29df3296186b"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{keterangan}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table 17" style="table 17" positionType="Float" x="39" y="103" width="475" height="52" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="5b51d0bf-d1e9-4745-8ade-b69474871a79">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 1" uuid="1c0dad36-2ce8-481d-aa16-738c65ddbcbe">
                    <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS2}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="28" uuid="3dd2aa48-6001-475e-8084-b71fe13e63ef">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="28" height="30" uuid="cc51c75b-a38f-4142-996b-ccb0e33503d6"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[No.]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="28" height="20" uuid="46b22f66-15b3-4819-a353-bb147e83f7af"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="136" uuid="a5200240-1b8e-48ff-a898-60de9a6d8956">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="136" height="30" uuid="f6e47ed7-3098-4c7f-a773-02b48b0c66d3"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Posisi TKA]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="136" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="64e41021-7e4d-4c7e-80e4-5ba3c2f7073c"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{posisiTka}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="67" uuid="2f7ca895-6e44-4f8d-8b74-01e074514361">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="67" height="30" uuid="60a909a9-e015-4bb5-8ecc-8e6b85b27570"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Dept.]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="67" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="dc8674f0-f94e-43b7-9d41-2fdde8873095"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{departemen}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="88" uuid="eb28444a-0f7a-4d0d-ae62-c3189cc73503">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="88" height="30" uuid="5cbf811c-eef7-49d0-8137-013b3b5e1a72"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Periode Penggunaan]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="88" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="db724659-5863-428a-ab7f-4dae8bd04d42"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{periode}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="157" uuid="ac699b7b-c128-4a90-bd72-caddb826c491">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 17_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="157" height="30" uuid="a0debb58-3628-4861-bf81-019f4dd7f638"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Keterangan]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 17_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="157" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="8b2d4d5a-80a1-4701-bfd5-519fd1c5f733"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{keterangan}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table 18" style="table 18" positionType="Float" x="39" y="181" width="474" height="70" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="0f49d051-fe9a-45ee-a5ab-d570a0b3b2e5">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 1" uuid="28d7100b-eb32-4d34-9222-0141bf26b9f3">
                    <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS3}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="32" uuid="0ab7278c-e13d-4233-9e82-350e39d1d96a">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 18_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="32" height="30" uuid="a41722a3-74fd-4e9d-ba1c-70e54eb0576d"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[No.]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 18_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="32" height="20" uuid="e91dfa23-53ba-4252-a23a-c03b72927b76"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="707eacdf-9a63-4142-bd34-6a325b7a9492">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 18_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="b8eaaa00-e9e6-47e3-a727-6273ed3e572f"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Nama Posisi Sebelumnya]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 18_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="996833d4-3fe3-4194-acef-6f8586b758ab"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{posisiSebelumnya}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="107" uuid="dca6e995-3c22-4996-99dd-874fdfab4890">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 18_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="107" height="30" uuid="90a99334-9730-4a70-957e-45ae46cf264e"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Perubahan Nama Posisi yang Disetujui]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 18_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="107" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ecf7a33f-3b75-4da9-9636-809887e4bfe3"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{posisiTka}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="64" uuid="4cc762f7-ec87-4fc2-b253-ac3035baed61">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 18_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="64" height="30" uuid="425a68df-2c74-4e22-8460-2e34707da3c5"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Dept.]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 18_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="64" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="386e3887-8962-4273-9d43-4843e9c87c03"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{departemen}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="448fb74b-aeff-4e4f-b92c-47718869e67f">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 18_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="8e8f5ec8-f2d2-4482-aad1-92a69e062f1f"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Periode Penggunaan]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 18_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="c0739140-feae-4f5e-bc92-5301f819d207"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{periode}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="91" uuid="d574582b-535a-47c6-a2d6-73eab6970a84">
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 18_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="91" height="30" uuid="88f0969f-f791-40fd-88f4-5db2df6d2403"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Keterangan]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 18_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="91" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="7cd271d1-0b72-41a8-8521-4b2b533924ff"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{keterangan}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="100" y="160" width="455" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="faf5ca75-b403-4120-bba0-d463876a7ce5"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{terbilangTable3}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="99" y="83" width="456" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="64e2c935-dbf3-4d4f-a8c9-7d7b264c3c1c"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{terbilangTable2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: I have edit your post some (feel free to edit again or rollback if you are not happy), there is no need to be in secure (maybe, ecc), furthermore if its not code (table width) do not use code block (use the block I used, or just a list)... trying to help out, hope you appreciate it.